# Different answers for the same dataset on applying Linear Regression! Why?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, data-science, gradient-descent

I have written a code for linear regression as follows:
The file data.csv has two columns: X and Y

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.T
    for i in range(numIterations):
        print 'Iteration : ',i+1 
        hypo = np.dot(x, theta)
        cost = np.sum((hypo-y)**2) / (2*m)
        print 'Cost : ', cost
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, (hypo-y)) / m
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
        print 'theta : ', theta
    return theta

data = np.loadtxt('/Users/Nikesh/Downloads/linear_regression_live-master/data.csv', delimiter=',')
x = data[:, 0:1]
y = data[:, 1:2]
a = np.ones((100,1))
x = np.append(a, x, axis=1)
m, n = np.shape(x) 
numIterations= 1000
alpha = 0.0005
theta = np.ones(n)
theta = theta[:, np.newaxis]
theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
```

The final output after 1000 iterations:

> Iteration :  1000 Cost :  56.014846105 theta :  [[ 1.1395461 ]  [
>   1.45709467]]

Here, I assume that y = 1.139 + 1.457X

The next code on the same dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

data = np.loadtxt('/Users/Nikesh/Downloads/linear_regression_live-master/data.csv', delimiter=',')
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(data[:, 0:1], data[:, 1:2])
print 'Co-efficients : ', regr.coef_
print 'Intercept : ', regr.intercept_
print 'Regression line : ',regr.intercept_,'+',regr.coef_,' X'
```

The Output is  :

> Co-efficients :  [[ 1.32243102]]   Intercept :  [ 7.99102099] 
>   Regression line :  [ 7.99102099] + [[ 1.32243102]]  X

And the final one which I found online. 
On the same dataset, on applying Linear Regression (Gradient Descent Alg)
[A different answer(take a look at this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wKn.png)

Could someone help me where I am going wrong?

Here is the link for the dataset : 
https://github.com/llSourcell/linear_regression_live/blob/master/data.csv

Comment: when the number of iterations is finite, the final value of theta does depend on its initial value and the value of alpha.

Comment: the learning rate is very less and I hope the algorithm is not taking huge steps in my iterations, theta values converges somewhere in the middle (~500iteration) and doesn't change from then @frederick99